# Dispatching a window message to sleep monitors works on mouse click but not keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, power-management

I have a C# Winforms system tray application which is supposed to put all my monitors to sleep when the icon clicked or on a keyboard screenshot.

To send the monitors to sleep I use this code

```
private int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
private uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

//For sleeping monitors
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void SchnozOff()
{
    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)2);
}
```

This code works fine when called from a MouseClick event handler

```
private void sysTrayIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        SchnozOff();
    } else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

However I also have it called on a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Alt + S). When I do this the monitors go to sleep but then immediately wake up again, even though I haven't touched the keyboard/mouse (the intended action to wake the monitors).

```
// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);


private const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
private void RegisterHotkeys()
{
     // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
     // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
     // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
     int Ctrl = 1;
     int Alt = 2;

     RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, Ctrl + Alt, (int)Keys.S);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
    {
        SchnozOff();
    }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/AlexDobsonPleming/Sleepy/tree/master) if it's helpful. I can assure you there isn't much more to see really though.

Comment: Maybe a latency issue (while other stuff is being processed). Try to add, e.g., `Thread.Sleep(200);` before you call `SendMessage()` -- BTW, you should check what `RegisterHotKey()` returns (and use `|` instead of `+`, even when this may result in the same value)

Comment: *"When I do this the monitors go to sleep but then immediately wake up again, even though I haven't touched the keyboard"* - Actually, you have. After you hit the registered hotkey combination you had to release those keys, right? That's keyboard input. I don't know whether that's what caused the observed behavior, but I wouldn't preclude it.

Comment: Forgot to mention: add `MOD_NOREPEAT = 0x4000` to the Key modifiers